# Проверка на наличие присутствия сертификата в системе

Tags: c#, x509certificate

Как проверить существует ли сертификат с заданным именем во всех каталогах хранилища Windows, я написал вот такой код, но он не работает:

```cs
public static string AntiBadSertificates()
{
    var x509store = new X509Store(StoreName.CertificateAuthority, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);            
    x509store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
    foreach (X509Certificate certificate in x509store.Certificates)
    {
        return certificate.ToString();
    }
    return string.Empty;    
}
     
public static void Main()
{
    if (Guard.AntiBadSertificates().Contains("Charles")  || Guard.AntiBadSertificates().Contains("fiddler"))
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

Сертификат присутствует в системе,но метод его не видит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну потому что вы возвращаете первый найденный сертификат в первой итерации цикла, и на этом история заканчивается.

Попробуйте так

```cs
public static IEnumerable<string> GetCertificates()
{
    var x509store = new X509Store(StoreName.CertificateAuthority, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    x509store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
    foreach (X509Certificate certificate in x509store.Certificates)
    {
        yield return certificate.ToString();
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (Guard.GetCertificates().Any(x => x.Contains("Charles") || x.Contains("fiddler")))
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо,очень помогли!